# Elasticsearch setting limits

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch I want to get more about some terminologies with example.
1.ES_HEAP_SIZE
2.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts
3.bootstrap.mlockall: true
4.MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
5.MAX_OPEN_FILES
6. transient
7.persistent
8. ulimit

Comment: Question is way to broad.

Answer (score 0):

Best way for you to understand is to read official docs

1. General Elasticsearch [setup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html)
2. [Set-up Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html)
3. [Index Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_settings.html)
4. Running as a [service](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-service.html) on Linux

If you need anything specific, let us know